# How to baseline align TextField and Text in HStack

Tags: alignment, textfield, swiftui

I have some trouble aligning TextFiled and Text in HStack.

The problem is with `.lastTextBaseline` alignment.

```
struct TextFieldCurrency: View {
    @State var value = "32"

    var body: some View {
         HStack(alignment: .lastTextBaseline) {
            TextField("price", text: $value)
                .background(Color.yellow)
                .modifier(TextFieldValueAppearance()) //font: 32
            Text("PLN")
                .background(Color.red)
                .modifier(TextFiledUnitAppearance()) //font: 16
         }.background(Color.green)
    }
}
```

Code above produces this which is totally wrong.

[image: TextField and Text in HStack - incorrectly alignment]

But the same code with Text instead TextField.

[image: Two Text view - correct alignment]

So, my questions are:

1. Why this happen? How is TextField different from Text?
2. What is solution to baseline alignment?

I have Xcode 11.2 and Mac OS Catalina 10.15.0

Comment: It appears TextField internally is not Text like view. It might be needed custom alignmentGuide usage.